# Unmarshall Value out of Class Attribute with JAXB

Tags: xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have an Xml I want to unmarshall with JAXB into Java Classes. Every single Class is working perfectly fine except for the class "Attribute" which contains a "Value". I tried to unmarshall the Value of the Attribute which is always a different Data type. Sometimes the Value is a String, sometimes its an int or a Double. I know there are Attributes and Elements in XML but this XML has an actual Element Called Attribute

```
<InstanceHierarchy Name="HMI">
    <InternalElement Name="name" RefBaseSystemUnitPath="somepath/" ID="123-45">
        <Attribute Name="Width" AttributeDataType="xs:Integer">
            <Value>800</Value>
        </Attribute>
    </InternalElement>
</InstanceHierarchy>
```

Hier is my Class Attribute:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "")
public class Attribute {

@XmlElement //here I have also tried @XMLValue
protected Value value;
@XmlAttribute(name = "Name")
protected String name;
@XmlAttribute(name = "AttributeDataType")
protected String attributeDataType;`
```

when I debug the value is always null (and with @XMLValue there the value variable reads "\n\t\t\t" ).

I must say beforehand that I have tried the following:

1. In Attribute Class defined the Value as:

   ```
   @XMLValue
   protected String value;
   ```
2. I also tried with @XMLElement and still getting nulls for Value

   ```
   @XmlElement(required = true)
   protected String value;
   ```

3.Then I decided to create a Class "Value" and unmarshall it that way as a String still doesnt work

4. So I made a completely new XML called "Note.xml" for testing pourposes and that Class I can unmarshal perfectly. "Attribute" still not working

[Note vs Attribute class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSmQe.png)

Can anybody help me get the value out of the xml? thank you all very much!

[here the value of Attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLN9F.png)

Comment: What's the class Value like? From XML perspective `800`it's just a string. Try `@XmlElement(type = Integer.class)` for `value` attribute (or BigInteger.class).

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Thanks Luis. I have also tried that. I have made a new section on the Post of things I have already tried... Still not working... :/